# Do socket connections only need one thread?

Tags: php, sockets, asyncsocket

As I understand, Apache isn't suited to serving long-poll requests, as each request into Apache will use one worker thread until the request completes, which may be a long time for long-poll/COMET requests.

But what about socket connections. On the PHP website I saw [an example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php#105735) of a *"simple multi-client server written in PHP that really works"*.

My question: Does such socket servers only use one worker thread for all established connections? And what about the opposite: Is it possible to write a PHP client which connects to several socket servers simultaneously using only one worker thread?

Answer (score 3):

Look at [phpDaemon](http://phpdaemon.net/). It design for long-pool applications and similar. But I advise you to use node.js for these tasks, if possible.

Comment: What's the license of this library? I only see that it supports SOCKS, can it handle socket connections?

Comment: In phpDaemon all protocols based on simple socket connection. You can use it directly or extend. See this examples https://github.com/kakserpom/phpdaemon/tree/master/app-servers Project does not contain information about the license. Try to contact with [author](https://github.com/kakserpom).

Answer (score 3):

That is an example of a polling-loop style server - see the `MSG_DONTWAIT` constant being passed to `socket_recv()`? Essentially, it has a single thread that loops through all of its open sockets to see if any of them has data waiting. If a socket doesn't have data waiting, it moves on to the next and checks it.

However, note that with such a server, you don't get nice protocol handling beyond the TCP base - you have to worry about parsing a stream of raw data yourself.

Comment: What do you mean with "protocol handling", could you explain it (for a newbie) in one or two sentences?

Comment: With a normal webserver, you automatically get things like parsing HTTP headers, etc. With sockets, all you get is a raw stream of bytes. It's up to you what those bytes mean.

Answer (score 3):

All of your connections are done with sockets. The main difference is whether I/O is blocking or not. Choosing to receive from a socket that blocks will cause the thread to block, but using `MSG_DONTWAIT` will finish immediately.

Apache gives you a few options in this regard. You can fork for concurrent connections (mpm-prefork), use a different thread for each connection (mpm-worker), or threads with non-blocking I/O (mpm-event).